# shiny: open new browser tab from within shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

From within shiny I want to open a HTML page in a new browser tab.
[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/ImTi-5SQavQ) it is pointed out that I need JS for that task. 
Let's say I want to open the URL http://www.google.com in a new tab from within my shiny app. I am not familiar with JS yet and I do not know which code where to include and how to call it from within the shiny app. How can I go about it?

Answer (score 26):

You shouldn't need anything more fancy than traditional, shiny-ified HTML:

```
a("test", href="http://google.com", target="_blank")
```

You're just looking to set the `target` attribute on the `a` tag which tells your browser where to open this new link you created.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. But I am wrong to assume that this simple creates an HTML link that will open in a new tab (or window)? What I want is something else: In the app you can press an action button which will trigger the process of collecting some input settings (from checkboxes etc.) and generate a new HTML document in the background. Now I could simply return a link to that new HTML document and let the user click it. What I want instead is to open this new HTML document  programmatically after the report generation is finished. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MarkHeckmann I am having a similar issue, I would like to knit my report based on a user action and then store that html file in the working directory. The issue I am having is I can knit the report, however I cannot display the report in a new tab automatically, so literally I just want to knit and render in a new tab. Did you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: @RickTastic: This is so long ago, and I am afraid I do not recall the project I needed it for nor what I did in the end, sorry!

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem and have come to the following solution. It's a bit of a workaround but it still works.
@MarkHeckmann: To start a new BrowserTab from a running Shiny App I use an action button which triggers the function `browseURL(...)`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Browser test"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        shiny::actionButton(inputId = "gen_report", label = "Generate Report")
     ),
     mainPanel(   )
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
observeEvent(input$gen_report,{
    browseURL("https://www.r-project.org")
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

@RickTastic: This procedure also works with self generated HTML reports. By listing an html page instead of a web address.
`browseURL("test.dashboard.html")` or `browseURL("path to html file")`

Comment: Tried adding this to my shiny app, received an error: `Remove browseURL calls; browseURL does not work in deployed applications.`

Comment: I didn't know that. Enventuell this solution helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426016/shiny-open-multiple-browser-tabs
Please let me know if this helps you

Answer (score 3):

I was  having a problem similar to this so I thought I would add my solution.

I wanted to have links in the tabPanel but Shiny will open a new blank page and have a link instead of just clicking on the tabPanel and opening a new page. Using the standard bootstrap CSS the workaround is to use the navbarMenu and then put the links in the tabPanel.

```
navbarMenu("Links",
           tabPanel(
               a("Google", href="https://google.com", target="_blank")
           )
```