# R Shiny - Open Downloadable File in a New Tab

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinydashboard

I am using R Shiny's downloadHandler/downloadLink functions to make an html file available for download. According to the default behavior, the file is downloaded to the system by the browser. However since the file that I am making available for download is an HTML file (.html), is there a way to open the file directly in a new browser tab instead of downloading the file to the system?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502661/shiny-open-new-browser-tab-from-within-shiny-app) on StackOverflow where it was suggested to add **target = "_blank"**. However, even this doesn't work for me.

My R Code:

```
# UI Code:
ui <- fluidPage(
        includeCSS("custom.css"),
        div(class = "intro-divider"),
        tags$style(".logo {
                 margin-left: 10px;
                 }"),
                 tags$div(class="logo", img(src="logo.gif", height='50px',width='350px')),
        br(),
        div(class = "intro-divider"),
        br(),
        h3("Title Page"),
        wellPanel(
          tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", '.well{width: 600px}')),
          h4("July 20, 2018"),
          tags$div(
            tags$ul(
              tags$li(downloadLink("july20_1", "Download HTML File", target = "_blank"))
            )
          )
        ) 
    )

# Server Code
server = function(input, output) {

      output$july20_1 <- downloadHandler(
                                filename = "july20_analysis_html.html",
                                content = function(file) {
                                file.copy("july20_analysis_html.html", file)
                                        })         
    }


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How do I make the file open directly into a new tab?

PS: I tested this app on Google Chrome browser.

Comment: You need to use the `<a>` tag for links.

Comment: @RyanMorton: Can you tell me where exactly to put the <a> tag in my code? That would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try: `tags$li(tags$a(downloadLink("july20_1", "Download HTML File", target = "_blank")))`

Comment: @RyanMorton: Thanks for the input. I tried that but it didn't work. :(