# How to auto redirect to tab in shiny without blocked by chrome by auto clicking link in shiny?

Tags: jquery, r, google-chrome, shiny, shinyjs

I would like the shiny app to auto redirect to the url in a new tab. I tried to use `window.open()`, but the popup will be blocked by chrome

**I also notice if the very first thing after clicking button is not to redirect the link, it will be blocked by chrome:**

```
# it works
actionButton("download", "Download link", onclick ="window.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com');")

# but it will not work
ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(),  
                actionButton("download", "Download link"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$download, {
   
  # some functions to generate the link
  ##### Note: it will take ~20s #####
  url <- funs(...) 

  # but lets use SO for now
  url <- "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
  # auto direct to the link in a new tab
  runjs(paste0("window.open('", url, "', '_blank');"))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I may think if there is any way to auto click the link tag below?

```
tags$a(href = "ww.google.com", "link to google", target = "_blank")
```

Edit:

I tried this way:

```
runjs(paste0(
      'let newTab = window.open();newTab.location.href = "https://www.stackoverflow.com";'
    ))
```

It somehow did not work in shiny: `VM238:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'location')`.

Comment: This work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/17513092 and redirects to new tab on click. Is that what you want?

Comment: @RonakShah I want it to auto redirect to new tab without user action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like no immediate solution to solve the issue if the auto redirection is not first thing after users click the button. It will be always blocked by chrome. Therefore, I give up auto redirection and have to add pop up box and ask users to click "ok" button.

```r
# something like below
ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(),  
                actionButton("download", "Download link"),
                uiOutput("linktext"))

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$download, {
   
  # some functions to generate the link
  ##### Note: it will take ~20s #####
  url <- funs(...) 
  output$linktext <- renderUI(tags$a(id="link-a", href = url, NULL, target = "_blank"))

  ## initiate fake popbox func to generate popup box
  popbox(inputId = "popup-box", "okay", "cancel")
}

observeEvent(input$popup-box, {
  req(input$popup-box == T)
  runjs("$('#link-a')[0].click();"))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

A hack would be to create a `<a>` element and simulate a click on this link:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(), 
                tags$a(id = "visit-so", 
                       href = "https://www.stackoverflow.com", 
                       "SO",
                       target = "_blank"), 
                actionButton("go", "Visit SO"),
                actionButton("go2", "Visit SO"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$go, runjs("$('#visit-so')[0].click();"))
  observeEvent(input$go2, runjs("$('<a>', {href: 'https://www.stackoverflow.com',
                                           target: '_blank'})[0].click();"))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So either you create the `<a>` element somewhere in your DOM for good, or you create a temporary `<a>` tag without appending it to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, it will work if the very first thing after click is to redirect. It is the same as `actionButton("test", "test", onclick ="window.open('https://www.google.com');")`.

Comment: I have updated my post. Are you able to solve my case: the link need ~20s to generate after users click the button. And then they are redirected to new tab once the link generated.

Comment: I don't get it. why not calling the `runjs` in the function which is generating the link once the link is available?

Comment: because the link I used in the app is the google spread sheet link, which need some functions to generate it. Once the link generate, then users can redirect to it.

Comment: If you shared they way how the spread sheet link is generated, I would be able to help. I assume there is some trigger to know programatically when the Google link is done, either because the generating function is onyl finished once the link is done, or a Google API call or as last resort some Javascript which continually checks if the link is existing....