# Open new webpage or empty browser tab from existing UI

Tags: r, shiny

I have shiny UI already built . Now I added new button . after clicking that button I want it to open new page on browser . I just want to display my leaflet output , how can I do that?
Here's my code below .

```
  observeEvent(input$show_map_view,{
    print(shapefile_output)
    print("BELOW THIS")
    logged_user <- Sys.info()[["user"]]
    zip_shp <- (paste0("C:/Users/",logged_user,"/Downloads","/",input$enter_file_name,".zip"))
    shp_1 <- paste0(input$enter_file_name,".shp")
    setwd(paste0("C:/Users/",logged_user,"/Downloads","/"))
    down_dir <- paste0("C:/Users/",logged_user,"/Downloads","/")
    unzip(zip_shp, exdir = down_dir)
    shpfile <- (paste0("C:/Users/",logged_user,"/Downloads","/",input$enter_file_name,".shp"))
    cb_shp_map <- readOGR(shpfile)
    print(cb_shp_map)
    output$show_map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(data = cb_shp_map) %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        setView(lat = 10 , lng = 0, zoom = 10) %>%
        addPolygons(fillColor = "green",
                    highlight = highlightOptions(weight = 5,
                                                 color = "red",
                                                 fillOpacity = 0.7,
                                                 bringToFront = TRUE),
                    label =~BLOCKID10)
      
       
    })
  })

ui.r (below)
ui <- dashboardPage(title = "MAPVIEW",
                    skin="blue",
                    header,
                    body=body,
                    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)
                    
                    

                    
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shiny: open new browser tab from within shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502661/shiny-open-new-browser-tab-from-within-shiny-app)

Comment: thanks for response but , as we can see in above code , my leaflet output is ready but I am unable to show it to my shiny dashboard page. do you have any suggestions ?